# address=data via macro define

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, casting, embedded

`#define PORTC *(unsigned char volatile *)(0x1003)`

`#define DDRC *(unsigned char volatile *)(0x1007)`

So I've been trying to read some stuff about embedded C. Initially I thought this macro was a pointer-to-pointer type but then I soon assumed the last star is actually a dereference rather than a type-cast, am I correct? Dereferencing to the location 0x1003/0x1007.

It is used like: `PORTC = <some hex value>`

Question is what makes this different from a pointer type-cast? Is there some sort of 'provision' in the C specifications? Or am I just an idiot...

Also I don't quite know how to phrase this and so I couldn't do a quick search first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way the C grammar is defined.

To be a cast, the expression needs parenthesis: `(type)sub-expression` casts `sub-expression` to type `type`.

Your example, `*(unsigned char volatile *)(0x1003)` is composed of 2 sub-expressions:

- a "lonely" star: `*`
- a cast: `(unsigned char volatile *)(0x1003)`

The cast is composed of the type inside `()` and a value.

So, the whole expression is interpreted as a pointer, then de-referenced to set the memory area pointed to.

Comment: So it needs to have a parenthesis to be a cast, eh? Thanks. Thinking back, casts without parenthesis makes less sense.

Comment: Right. With no parenthesis it's either a declaration or an illegal construct.

Comment: And really you need more parentheses around the whole expression to make explicit the precedence of the outermost `*`. i.e. `#define PORTC (*(unsigned char volatile *)(0x1003))`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is quite a cast.

First, the memory location (as integer) is cast into an appropriate pointer which is then dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

That code is basically equivalent to: Put `<some hex value>` in the memory at the address (0x1003) (or whatever the value is). In some embedded devices (and not only) ports are mapped at memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

The cast instructs the compiler that the memory addresses `0x1003` and `0x1007` are to be treated as `unsigned char volatile *` pointers, and the `*` dereferencing operator acts on that pointer to fetch the pointed-to value, which in this case is 1 byte.

Applying the unary `*` makes this expression a valid lvalue (it wouldn't be so without it) which means that it is something you can assign to.